# Full text search in XPages works on text fields, fails on date and number fields

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I have an xpage inside an indexed Lotus Notes database. There is a view control on the xpage (its data source being a Notes view), and since I plan to add a search text field to the xpage, I have been testing the view control "search" property (data\data\search). The documents on the database have text, date and numeric fields. When I look for something located on one of the text fields (e.g., koala), it works, but when I look for a date or a number no documents are found.

I wonder if this could be a localization problem, since in Spain we write the dates with format dd/mm/yyyy and the decimal character in numbers is the comma, but I also tried searching with format mm/dd/yyyy and using the point for decimals, and still no results are retrieved.

I also tried changing the searchFuzzy property on the view control, but nothing changed.

Thanks a lot,

Carlos

Comment: It should work the same. There might be issue with locale settings - XPage works with server's locale. Double check Domino AND OS settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you post the search syntax you're using? It's hard to diagnose the exact cause. Dates and times definitely work in full text searches.

I'm sorry in advance if you've already excluded any of these. The page in the Notes Help entitled "How can I refine a search query using operators" defines the correct syntax for full text searching, that will allow you to confirm you've got the right syntax.

Also, try doing the same search in the search bar of a view in Notes client. That will help diagnose if it's a problem with search criteria or XPages. (I've used searches in a variety of databases and I'm not aware of any specific problems in XPages.)

Also, have the field data types changed or do you use the same field name for different data types. Notes holds a separate table of the data type assigned to a field name. Once a document is created that has that field, that's the data type used for full text searching. It's not form specific. So if you have a field MyDate that's text on one form and date on another, you can't search both ways. http://www.intec.co.uk/full-text-search-musings/

Comment: Thanks a lot for your advice. The "How can I refine a search query using operators" you pointed me too is great, I have limited experience in Notes and I did not know that the search syntax can be so complex!

Comment: As for the problem at hand, it turns out that I always surrounded the search text with double quotes, and they prevented the search from working on numeric and date fields.